# Why does my Crawler get the wrong HTML code?

Tags: java, web-crawler

I've wanted to write a crawler in java for some school exercise. Actually the crawler code, implemented with the jsoup lib, worked because the result of my request was some HTML code, but when I searched for a word which was clearly written on the website, it was not found, because some **div's** from the crawler where **empty**.

Then I recognized, that I got the **same code as** you can see when you navigate to the website and **right-click -> 'view page source'**. 
When I compared the code to **right-click -> 'inspect'**, the **code was not the same** as in 'view page source'.

Is there anything I could do to get the HTML code containing the full content?

requested URL: https://app.libertex.com/?lang=deu&_ga=2.222573595.1459393376.1568209606-1642141519.1566978579&_gac=1.53153498.1566978579.CjwKCAjwzJjrBRBvEiwA867byuxkXf35eSWyL2LJhLel3PRiGsSfvU6iLb00E21dQOkogLcx_z5G6hoCQgwQAvD_BwE

Comment: You don't see everything because the webpage is full of dynamic content which isn't initially present on the page. I don't know how to fix this, maybe selenium can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't get the right code with jsoup as this website loads content dynamically.**

This webpage loads code dynamically, i.e. it loads the initial content and then executes other code to load the rest of the content. jsoup is merely an HTML parser, meaning that it can parse through the various content which it is given. It cannot execute Javascript or wait for external files to load.

To scrape a website like this, you probably need an automated browser of sorts. I personally use Selenium in Python for crawling websites which load dynamically.